# Halachic competition in business

Tags: business

How does one compete in a exclusively Jewish market (Judaica, kosher food business etc.), in the face of issues like taking away a competitor's [*marupia*](http://www.daat.ac.il/encyclopedia/value.asp?id1=628)?

Comment: what is marupia?

Comment: Are you talking about the halachos of *hasagas gvul*? The details of every case would make a difference and require a psak from a **local** Rav who knows the halachos, the individual involved, and the local business community. As an example a store whose main business is online is different from one whose main business is from walk-in customers. Both of those differ from one whose main business is from "regulars" in the community. This might be too broad to answer as well as requiring a local Rav to pasken.

Answer (score 2):

Marupia only applies if you specifically go after a competitors exclusively loyal customers. Marupia would not apply if you advertise to the general public. Furthermore even in a case of only a Jewish business there are those to be makel on.

Comment: I cannot find the definition of the word marupia, what is it.

Comment: This answer could be improved with some sources. Shavua tov.